# How to show/render product attributes by category selection during product creation in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-attribute

There is by default coming product attributes in Product Information during product creation from `Catalog->Manage Products->Add Product` in admin after creating product attribute and setting it in Attribute set.

But the requirement is that product attribute will be coming by category selection. For example, If I select saree category, then the saree related product attribute will be coming in product Information during product creation in magento admin.

I have googled a lot. But there is no fruitful result by which I can start this type of requirement.

Comment: where you select the saree category?

Comment: As usual, in Product information of admin->Catalog->Manage Products->Add/Edit Product, I select category (like Saree) from Categories tab of left panel....

Answer (score 0):

What about creating an attribute set for each category, so you can choose the right attribute set and so you get the right attributes.